# Heroku rails 4 asset folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using Rails v4 application deployed to Heroku.

Problem is files in /public/assets (any js/css file) returns 404.

I bashed into /assets folder to check if files exist, and it is. so precompile is working in production env.

Feel like its permission problem, but I think I should not modify..

What else can I check ?

Comment: Did you add `gem 'rails_12factor'` to your Gemfile?

Comment: @meagar Perfectly working! thanks!! :)

Comment: @Nate Glad to hear it.